# Hands on description of $X\times_G Y$, where $X$, $Y$ are varieties with group action from $G$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions, affine-varieties

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are algebraic varieties, where $X$ is a right $G$-set, and $Y$ is a left $G$-set. Then $X\times_G Y$ is usually defined be the quotient of $X\times Y$ by the diagonal left action where $g$ acts by $(g^{-1},g)$.

Is it roughly correct to informally picture elements of this quotient as pairs $(x,y)$, where we can "commute" elements of $g$ across the comma, so that $(x,gy)=(xg,y)$ in $X\times_G Y$? I'm thinking of this as being analogous to the tensor product $A\otimes_R B$ where we view simple tensors concretely as satisfying relations like $a\otimes rb=ar\otimes b$, if $A$ is a right $R$-module, and $B$ a left $R$-module.

If I am incorrect, what is the best way to think of this quotient when attempting to do something hands on, like exhibiting an explicit isomorphism of $G$-sets or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking quotients of algebraic varieties by group actions is generally poorly behaved - the general goal of geometric invariant theory is to understand / work around this.

So, at this level of generality, the description you give of the balanced product $X \times_G Y$ is not correct. If you were only taking a quotient *as sets* then yes, $X \times_G Y$ would just be the orbit space of $X \times Y$ as a $G$-set.

But that quotient may be topologically ugly (e.g. non-Hausdorff), and may not exist as an algebraic variety. (And conversely, a different variety $Z$ may exist that satisfies a universal property with respect to G-equivariant morphisms from $X \times Y$, hence acts as a ['categorical' quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_quotient). Typically the points of $Z$ correspond to *closures* of orbits rather than individual orbits, identifying any two orbits whose closures intersect.)

For example, let $Y$ be a point with a trivial $G$-action, so that $X \times_G Y = X/G$. Then for instance $X = \mathbb{A}^1$ with the scaling action by $G = \mathbb{G}_m$ ($t \cdot x \mapsto tx$) results in a poorly-behaved *set* quotient: two points, one of which is in the closure of the other. By contrast, the closest algebraic variety is just *one* point, corresponding to the closure of the large orbit (and is just $\mathrm{Spec}$ of the invariant subring $k[x]^G \subset k[x]$).